# Copying query results in to Excel file

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I'm trying to copy the results of my query into an excel file:

```
COPY
    (select c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name AS full_name,
COUNT (p.amount) AS "NUMBER OF TRANSACTIONS",
SUM (p.amount) AS "SUM OF TRANSACTIONS",
ROUND (AVG(p.amount),1) AS "AVERAGE TRANSACTION"
FROM CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN payment p
ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY full_name
ORDER BY "AVERAGE TRANSACTION")

TO '/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/database/Book2.csv'
DELIMITER ',';
```

however I keep getting the response:

> could not open file "/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/database/Book2.csv"
> for writing: Permission denied HINT:  COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL
> server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility
> such as psql's \copy. SQL state: 42501

I've tried with the doing /copy but then I get the ERROR:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/" LINE 1: /COPY
> ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 1

I'm not really sure what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/database/` a directory on the machine the server runs on?

Comment: And `/copy` is a `psql` command not an SQL statement, as the message clearly states. That is, it won't work in pgAdmin or any client other than `psql`.

Comment: @stickybit I have no problem importing files from that folder, only copying to.

Comment: Has the user the server runs under write permissions on that directory?

Comment: I gave full disk access to pgadmin, and everyone can read and write on the csv file i'm trying to copy to. I think my code is correct?

Comment: pgAdmin isn't the server, it's the **client**. Again: The **server** needs to be able to write in that directory.

Comment: postgres, psql shell, terminal, all have full disk access.

Comment: Obviously not... What OS do you use? Since you say that programs have access... usually *users* are used to set access rights.

Comment: I'm using macOS BigSur. Can see that a lot of others are having/had similar issues. I found the 'Save results to file' button on PGadmin, which did what i wanted to do. Still, woulda prefered to do it in code and fix this issue. Thanks for your help kind stranger!

Comment: Hmm, OK. I don't really know how such things work in MacOS, sorry.

Comment: @stickybit. It is actually `\copy` in `psql`. `/copy` will get you the syntax error Painkilleryo is showing.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Well spotted, I missed that. Thanks for correcting this!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming using `psql`. In a file named say csv_out.sql:

```
\pset format csv
\o out.csv
select c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name AS full_name,
COUNT (p.amount) AS "NUMBER OF TRANSACTIONS",
SUM (p.amount) AS "SUM OF TRANSACTIONS",
ROUND (AVG(p.amount),1) AS "AVERAGE TRANSACTION"
FROM CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN payment p
ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY full_name
ORDER BY "AVERAGE TRANSACTION";
\o
\pset format align
```

Then in `psql`:

```
\i csv_out.sql
```

If you invoke `psql` from the command line in a script, you may find the `--csv` option useful:

```sh
psql --csv -c 'SELECT ...'
```

See here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) for more information under `\pset format`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pgAdmin4's Import/Export option on your respective table which will allow you to export your data in various formats like CSV/TSV.